# OSGi and Persistence Units

Tags: java, dynamic, properties, persistence, osgi

Good day guys, I'm programming an `OSGi` bundle in charge of authenticating users. For design reasons I'm obligated to perform queries over multiple database schemas (these schemas can be created or deleted dynamically). I'm running `MySQL` as storage engine.

Somehow I need to be able to create on demand entity managers for those schemas, but I haven't been successful in my attempts. Here is what I have tried that has got me closer to what I need:

Creating a persistence unit (Eclipselink) using a JTA data source that can, in fact, establish a database connection to the default schema. However, when I try to override any property, say, the ***`javax.persistence.jdbc.url`***. However, it keeps pointing to the default schema always.

I believe I'm not overriding correctly the property, or that JTA datasource properties cannot be modified from `EntityManager` to `EntityManager`. Here is how I create the EntityManagers:

```
Map<String, String> dbProps = new HashMap<String, String>();            
dbProps.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url","jdbc:mysql://mydomain:3306/mydynamicdb);                                                        
EntityManagerFactory fact = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistenceUnit", dbProps); 
EntityManager myEM = fact.createEntityManager();
```

At the end, they all keep poiting to the default schema, so my questions are:

1. Is this an efficient approach for dynamic EntityManager handling? if so, how can I override effectively the schema property?
2. Is there any other alternative besides the overriding?

I thank you in advance for any guidance you may provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use EclipseLink in OSGi you must use the [Gemini JPA](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/jpa/) project that wraps EclipseLink and create and register an EntityManagerFactory and an EntityManagerFactoryBuilder services for your PU bundle. 
If want to share the jdbc connections between PUs you can use JDBC services provided by [Gemini DBAccess](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/dbaccess/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to acquire the `EntityManagerFactory` as an OSGi service, you can (LDAP) filter the correct one using the service property `osgi.unit.name` as in:

```
    ServiceReference[] refs = null;        
    String filter = "(osgi.unit.name=myPersistenceUnit)";
    ServiceReference[] refs = ctx.getServiceReferences(EntityManagerFactory.class.getName(), filter);
    //Should only be one reference, check (throw exception etc)
    return (EntityManagerFactory)ctx.getService(refs[0]);
```

You can check that all Persistence Units are present, by listing the EntityManagerFactory services (with properties) in your OSGi shell.